# Angular Boostrap Pricing

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

Have someone used the bootstrap libraries specific for angular( ng-bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap) and was also informed about its pricing ? I don't know if I have to pay for a license when I want to use this libraries in a production project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [ng-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap) and [ngx-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-bootstrap) are [MIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) licensed, which says:

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> [...]

[In short](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/LICENSE):

> Permissions
>
> - Commercial use
> - Modification
> - Distribution
> - Private use
>
> Limitations
>
> - Liability
> - Warranty

Answer (score 0):

As a one of the devs, who maintains ngx-bootstrap, I can say, that it's 100% OSS and free :)

Feel free to use it, add some suggestions, contribute, .etc